# Screen blurry, overflows visible area in Gnome classic on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, nvidia

I'm having a lot of trouble getting things setup to work nicely with my monitors in 11.10.

I have an "old" VGA connected 19" Acer monitor to the left (secondary) and a newer, HD Acer monitor connected over DVI to the right (primary).

The graphics card on the machine is Nvidia 9500 GT. It's using the optional drivers that you install from the additional drivers menu.

I had a ton of problems initially getting setup with the secondary screen, it's supposed to have a resolution of 1440x900 and it wasn't being set to this.

Now the problem I have is that the primary monitor doesn't appear to be in full HD any more, it looks blurry and some of the "stuff" at the bottom of any given window is cut off, it's gone beyond where the screen ends.

I'm not really sure how to go about fixing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this is going to sound ridiculous. But I switched the screen itself off and on again and it is working now.